# 550 The directory name is invalid

Tags: unix, ftp

I am having a bit of trouble with a UNIX FTP over TLS script. When i am pulling files (copying to localhost) there is no problem however when i go to remove the file from the remote Windows server i am receiving the FTP error `550 The directory name is invalid` I am trying to figure out what is causing this, when checking with the system admin for the Windows machine they state that the account i am connecting with has the appropriate delete rights to complete this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The following is after connecting using ftp -s and logging in.

```
ftp> passive 

Passive mode  on.

ftp> ls -al

227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,2,50,238,107).

125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.

TLSv1/SSLv3 ( AES128-SHA ), 128 bits

02-04-13  01:47PM                27696 20130204T134747Z.csv 

02-05-13  01:36PM                 3423 20130205T133659Z.csv

02-08-13  03:40PM                 2674 appimport.csv

02-03-13  03:14PM       <DIR>          aspnet_client

02-25-13  03:07PM                 6566 exportedAll.csv

226 Transfer complete.

ftp> rm exportedAll.csv
```

**ERROR:** 550 The directory name is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ftp> delete exportedAll.csv
```

`rm` is short for `rmdir`, so it only works to remove a directory, not ordinary files.

Comment: rm is used for files in UNIX from everything I have seen with rmdir being used for the directories. Do you have another command that you reccomend using?

Comment: This isn't Unix, it's the `ftp` command. It has its own language. Type `?` to see all the commands that are available there.

Comment: Excellent this worked I feel kinda silly not thinking about the fact that ftp is more or less a program outside of my host OS. Went in saaw delete as an option tried it out works great. Thank you